# PouchDB filtered replication from couchDB not filtering

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

Old versions of my app are uploading outdated files to my couchDB database.
Here is my couchDB design doc for filtering

```
"function(doc, req) {    
  if(doc._id === '_design/app') {
    return true;
  }
  if(doc._id.slice(0, 8) == '_design/') {
    return false;
  }
  if (doc.username === 'localUser' || !doc.username || doc._id == 'databaseversion') {
return false;
  }
}"
```

As you can see documents that don't have a username are supposed to be excluded. But some of them are still replicating. Below is how I start the replication in PouchDB. Do I need to make vocabcouchdb the src and localdb the target so that the design doc on vocabcouchdb is used to check what to filter before anything else?

```
syncObjWords = PouchDB.sync(localdb, vocabcouchdb, {
        live: true,
        retry: true,
        filter: 'app/reject_other_users_personal_words',
        query_params: {
          'username': $rootScope.globalUserData.username
        }
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

I eventually solved this. I think it was just old versions of apps on other devices with different syncing rules syncing things they shouldn't. To fix it I added a syncVersion key to each document. Now I can filter by the version so that old installations of the app don't sync things that are outdated.